# Multiple ag-grid tables causing browser to hang

Tags: angular, performance, google-chrome, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am working on a dashboard and having multiple ag-grid tables. These tables have their own data-fetch mechanism (polling or data via web-sockets). Total having 7 tables out of which 4 rely on web-sockets and rest 3 on polling for data.

On receiving data normally we do :

1. Add/remove data
2. Flashing of cells
3. Cell styling (based on data received )
4. some custom checks

When we get frequent updates (say 500 events per minute on a page updating ag-grid data ) page becomes unresponsive and it starts showing **sluggishness** even scrolling inside the table becomes difficult. And if we have opened 3-4 tabs of the same dashboard CPU execution shoots up to 100% within 10 mins and White screen of death can be seen in inactive tabs.

When checked with the performance tab :

[image]

[image]

[image]

With the last image, it can be seen the **idle time** is very less and 80% is the script running time.

I have created the repo of our ag-grid configuration and what we do after we receive data :
[ag-grid load issue](https://github.com/monis001/ag-grid-load-test)

[What I have already tried] :

1. Immutable data source with web-workers (limitation I fall into is cannot use ag-grid functions like `gridApi.getRowNode` to get the nodes inside web-workers )

Any suggestions for improvement or some direction to look for performance will be helpful.

Thanks

P.S.:

1. Above repo code is not executable (because we have some server configuration) but enough to give you an idea of how things are set-up and how it is executing.
2. Moreover, we have an ag-grid widget component that is normally `ng-repeat` on the page with server configuration and tables are rendered on the page.
3. We do not have such 10,000 rows(maximum rows in one of the table is up to 450 ) etc. but the operations are very frequent, like flashing of cells/ running cell style functions.
4. what our tables look like : (one of the tables)
   [image]

Comment: I also had bad experience with ag-grid where it was had high cpu usage for apparently no reason. But in your case: Why do you need to update the grid 500 times a minute ? I would just cache the data and update the grid on some safe interval, let's say once in a  seconds or so.

Comment: By 500, It's the collective total events that 4 grids receive in a minute, so for example consider it like you have live trading data going on. So one grid is reflecting a number of active users, one grid is reflecting the user's activity another grid is reflecting the status of tickets raised by these active users, etc. so when tested with limits of these users or say the events grid recieve, it starts showing sluggishness or even if 2-3 tabs are open (what normally a user does)  than it turns out to be very costly execution

Comment: One thing that's not mentioned anywhere is the aggrid callbacks are way too slow and use a lot of memory. After handling click manually from JS onclick instead of the aggrid callback, my click operation became much faster event though there was very little change in the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

As [user2555515](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2555515/user2555515) said in a comment, you'll want to cache data updates and update the actual grid less often. This is a browser limitation as much as (or more than) an ag-grid limitation - I'm pretty sure that there's only one foreground (painting) thread.

First thing is to realize that the grid is not your data store - you should store your data in your component, and bind that data to the grid.

You can have the incoming data update a copy of your data store that is not bound to the grid, and only copy it over to the bound version at regular intervals, like once per second.

And for potentially better-performing "batch updates", the grid api supports "transactions".